# mouseover mouseout not working animation on multiple ul's

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-animate, mouseover, mouseout

Does anybody know how to make my script work for multiple ul's?

Please take a look at [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Autodealers/YFUsJ/).
As you can see, the script only works for the second ul on mouseover.

Thank you in advanced!
With Kind Regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let me explain, what was happening. you were only selecting the last created div, so only that one was going.

I had to find the selected `.active` and the selected `div`

Here is example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaPack/YFUsJ/23/

In `mouseover` i added this to the top to change `active` and `animation` vars

```
    active = $(this).parent().find('.active');
    animation = $(this).parent().find('div');
```

In `mouseout` i added this.

```
    active = $(this).find('.active');
    animation = $(this).find('div');
```

**EDIT:**
For the problem with moving the class `active` to other `<li>` objects, you have to append the `<div>` for each `.active` class separately
Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaPack/YFUsJ/31/

What I did was wrap the animation var into a `.each`

```
$.each(active, function() {
    var animation = $('<div>').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'height': $(this).outerHeight()-1,
        'width': $(this).outerWidth(),
        'marginTop': ($(this).parent().index() * $(this).outerHeight()),
        'borderBottom': '1px solid #000',
        'z-index': -10
    });
    $(this).parent().parent().prepend(animation);
});
```

Instead or prepending to the `<ul>` like before, I did it to the parent of the parent which should always be there for a menu with the class `active`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua! You are getting close, because when I move the active class to another anchor, it doesn't work properly.. Can you take another look for me? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Smart move! Thnx on this one.